# How to obtain a list of users using weak passwords in a Google Apps domain

Tags: google-admin-sdk

In the online dashboard provided by Google a list of users using weak passwords can be seen (passwordmonitoring). This list is limited to +- 15 visible entries. One can scroll in this list but for follow-up of thousands of users this is not practical.
Can this list be obtained via scripting? or scraping the dashboard website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no public API that allows you to programatically determine password strength for a user. You should also be aware that screen scraping is against Google's ToS and generally ends up with your account being locked.